# Change the keys of an array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've an array like below :

`$array = array('string'=>'hello','somethingeElse'=>'how r u', ....);`

I wanna change the keys of array to numeric values (consecutive):

`$array = array('1'=>'hello','2'=>'how r u','3'=>....);`

any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Just loop through the array and change the keys as needed.

Comment: This is a pretty straighforward task. What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function, which will basically do what you say.

> array_values() returns all the values from the input array and indexes
>   numerically the array.

**Example:**

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid PHP loops, you may try something like :

```
$newArray = array_combine(range(1, count($array)), array_values($array));
```